# How to compute horizontal gradient value?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, coding-style, gradient

So I want to measure the vertical edges of an image to use it later as depth cue for 2D to 3D conversion.

To do so I will have to compute the horizontal gradient value for each block to measure the vertical edges as follow:

```
̅ g(x,y) = 1/N  ∑_((x',y')∈ Ω(x,y))〖g(x', y')〗
```

Where:

g(x',y') is a horizontal gradient at a pixel location (x',y'),

omega(x,y) is the nighborhood of the pixel location(x',y')

and N is the number of pixels in omega(x,y).

*So Here is what I did on matlab*:

```
I = im2double(imread('landscape.jpg'));

% convert RGB to gray
gI = rgb2gray(I);
[nrow, ncol] = size(gI);

% divide the image into 4-by-4 blocks
gI = mat2tiles((gI),[4,4]);

N = 4*4; % block size

% For each block, compute the horizontal gradient  
gI = reshape([gI{:}],4*4, []);
mask = fspecial('sobel');
g = imfilter(gI, mask);
g_bar = g./N;


g_bar = reshape(g_bar,nrow, ncol);
```

I'm new to Matlab so I'm not sure if my code is expressing the equation in the right way.

Can you please let me know if you think it is correct? as I'm not sure how to test the output!

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest having a look at [`blockproc`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) - that's probably nicer (and quicker) than all the `reshape`-juggling.

Comment: Sidenote: Take a look at my research.  My PhD thesis was on 2D to 3D conversion - http://scholar.google.ca/citations?user=5piX29gAAAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for you to decompose your image into 4 x 4 blocks.  The horizontal gradient can be used with a Sobel filter or Prewitt filter, which is 3 x 3 and can directly be put into `imfilter`.  `imfilter` performs 2D convolution / filtering with a specified mask / kernel for you, so tiling is not necessary.  As such, you can just use `imfilter` with the mask defined through `fspecial`, and define `N = 9`.  Therefore:

```
I = im2double(imread('landscape.jpg'));

% convert RGB to gray
gI = rgb2gray(I);

N = 9;

mask = fspecial('sobel');
g = imfilter(gI, mask);
g_bar = g./N;
```

From experience, increasing the size of your gradient mask won't give you much better results.  You want to ensure that the mask is as small as possible to capture as many local changes as possible.

Comment: So this is the way to compute the local gradient, right?

Comment: @user2833205 - Yes.  Why would you want to global gradient?  That has no practicality.  The whole point of the local gradient is to determine local changes in your image.  Doing it globally would lose all of this.

Comment: @user2833205 - As far as I know, there is no such thing.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that the global gradient can help me find the global depth map of an image, and then I would update the global depth map based on the local features.

Comment: The problem with that is that if the global gradient is inaccurate, any changes you make locally will not improve the results.  I wouldn't recommend global gradient TBH.  The whole point of local gradient is to get local changes.  Finding the "global" gradient would mean you have a function that represents the image and you are calculating the gradient based on that... and you don't have that available

Comment: But this is how the professor is asking us to find the depth map by "finding the global depth map and then updating it based on local features". Thus, I though of finding the global gradient. Do you have any other suggestion on finding the global depth map?

Comment: AH OK.  What he means by "global depth map" is that you minimize a cost function that computes the best depths overall in the image.  You find the best depths for each pixel that reduce the cost of a cost function.  The reason why it's global is because you are using global optimization.  The gradient and all of that should only be applied locally. Take a look at my research on more details.  Another good example would be Saxena's work: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/